# How to usage PFSystemKit in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I'm trying to use the library PFSystemKit. But I faced with the fact that I can not import it . Maybe someone used it and can suggest how to properly use ? I build framework and add in my project. But i have few issue.
[image]

Comment: How are you trying to add it to your project?

Comment: @Abizern i add how framework. I'll update the question. Maybe you can help ?

Comment: Are you adding the framework built for iOS or OSX? The project contains both targets.

Comment: @Abizern I adding framework build for ios in  my ios project.

Comment: How are you building the framework? Are you building a fat framework that will also run in the simulator? The way I add frameworks is I add it as a sub-project of my project and set a dependency on the correct framework target (iOS or OSX) and build the framework along with my target. This makes sure the correct versions get built.

Comment: @Abizern i build PFSystemKit - ios and get generate framework and adding in my project.